# MongoDB query to get all documents matching with key with mutliple values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have documents in `mongodb` which has a `transaction_id`. Data type of `transaction_id` is `ObjectId`.

If I do below query, I get the document:

```
db.collection.find({ 'transaction_id': ObjectId('609cfef4ad16361274eb12e2') })
   .projection({})
   .sort({_id:-1})
   .limit(100)
```

But what if I want to get all the documents for multiple transaction ids. So I did:

```
db.collection.find({ 'transaction_id': [ObjectId('609cfef4ad16361274eb12e2'), ObjectId('609cfeecad16361274eb12e1')] })
   .projection({})
   .sort({_id:-1})
   .limit(100)
```

I get no documents. How can I get all the documents for matching transaction ids. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `in` operator:

```
db.collection.find( { 'transaction_id': { $in: [ObjectId('609cfef4ad16361274eb12e2'), ObjectId('609cfeecad16361274eb12e1')] } } )
```